# How can I match the given pattern using Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input:

`-key1:"val1" -key2: "val2" -key3:(val3) -key4: "(val4)" -key5: val5 -key6: "val-6" -key-7: val7 -key-eight: "val 8"`

With only the following assumption about the pattern:

- Keys always start with a `-` followed by a value delimited by `:`

How can I match and extract each *key* and it's corresponding *value*?

I have so far come up with the following *regex*:

`-(?<key>\S*):\s?(?<val>\S*)`

But it's currently not matching the complete value for the last argument as it contains a *space* but I cannot figure out how to match it.

The expected output should be:

- key1 "val1"
- key2 "val2"
- key3 (val3)
- key4 "(val4)"
- key5 val5
- key6 "val-6"
- key-7 val7
- key-eight val 8

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you passing all key , value in single string or iterating over it ?

Comment: What about simply removing that last space after this regex? No big deal

Comment: What is your desired output/outcome?

Comment: So... the space is part of the value or part of the key? ... can you give an example of in and output as Tim suggested?

Comment: @popeye, yes all keyvals are in a single line which will be matched against the regex to extract each keyval.

Comment: I got it, presuming that a value containing a whitespace followed immediately by a hyphen is unallowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing that you want to only allow whitespace characters that are not at the beginning or end, change your regex to:

```
-(?<key>\S*):\s?(?<val>\S+(\s*[^-\s])*)
```

This assumes that the character `-` preceeded by a whitespace unquestioningly means a new key is beginning, it cannot be a part of any value.

For this example:

`-key: value -key2: value with whitespace            -key3: value-with-hyphens -key4: v`

The matches are:
`-key: value`, `-key2: value with whitespace`, `-key3: value-with-hyphens`, `-key4: v`.

It also works perfectly well on your provided example.

Comment: This looks very good, currently doing more testing on a bigger dataset. Will report back shortly.

Comment: Looks like the one to me :)

Comment: Yep, Does the job as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're wanting to keep the brackets and quotation marks as that's what you're doing in the example you gave? If so then the following should work:

```
-(?<key>\S+):+\s?(?<val>\S+\s?\d+\)?\"?)
```

This does presume that all val's end with a number though.

**EDIT:**
Given that the val doesn't always end with a number, but I'm guessing it always starts with val, this is what I have:

```
-(?<key>\S+):+\s?(?<val>\"?\(?(val)+\s?\S+)
```

Seems to be working properly...

Comment: Your first assumption is correct but the values do not necessarily end with a number.

Comment: Ah, and they don't necessarily end with a bracket or quotation mark either haha. That makes it a little trickier.

Comment: This is working almost perfectly fine although it requires that the value should end with a numeric value

Comment: Nice try but again, as I mentioned above, you cannot assume anything other than `Keys always start with a - followed by a value delimited by :`

Comment: Ahhh, you're killing me here hahaha ;)

Answer (score 1):

A low tech (non regex) solution, just for an alternative. Trim guff, `ToDictionary` if you need

```
var results = input.Split(new[] { " -" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(x => x.Trim('-').Split(':'));
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eKLqfQ)

**Output**

```
key1 -> "val1"
key2 ->  "val2"
key3 -> (val3)
key4 ->  "(val4)"
key5 ->  val5
key6 ->  "val-6"
key-7 ->  val7
key8 ->  "val 8"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/wRP0np/1) using Replace function:

```
(?:^|(?!\S)\s*)-|\s*:\s*
```

and replace with "\n". You should get key values in separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
-(?<key>\S*):\s*(?<value>(?(?=")((")(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1))(\S*))
```

a sample link can be found [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%28%3F%3Ckey%3E%5CS*%29%3A%5Cs*%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%28%3F%28%3F%3D%22%29%28%28%22%29%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3D%28%5C%5C%3F%29%29%5C2.%29*%3F%5C1%29%29%28%5CS*%29%29&i=-key1%3A%22val1%22%20-key2%3A%20%22val2%22%20-key3%3A%28val3%29%20-key4%3A%20%22%28val4%29%22%20-key5%3A%20val5%20-key6%3A%20%22val-6%22%20-key-7%3A%20val7%20-key8%3A%20%22val%208%22).
Basically it does and if/else/then to detect if the value contain `"` as `(?(?=")(true regex)(false regex)`, the false regex is yours `\S*` while the true regex will try to match start/end quote `(")(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1)`.